# adding and reading a JSON asset in Flutter Web app

Tags: json, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, assets

Got a problem reading an asset in Flutter web app. I've declared it in pubspec.yaml

[image]

But when I'm trying to load it with `await rootBundle.loadString('test/sample_text.json');` I always get the same error `Error while trying to load an asset: Failed to load asset at "assets/test/sample_text.json"` 
Never had such issue when developing for mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the correct way to do this is `packages/$your_package/assets/test/sample_text.json`

Answer (score 1):

Assets in the web are placed under another `assets/` directory, which results in the path being `assets/assets/....`

Create a simple function e.g. in lib/utils.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

String path(str) {
  return (kIsWeb) ? 'assets/$str' : str;
}
```

Wrap any path strings with this function, for example

```
AssetImage(path('assets/test/sample_text.json')).
```

Comment: so you're proposing to do the same assets/test/sample_text.json. As I mentioned in my question, it doesn't work

Comment: I have edited my answer. It should be ‘assets/assets/test/sample_text.json’